# Shed on concrete pier blocks - how to brace laterally?

Tags: foundation, shed, pier-blocks

I'm building a shed on concrete pier blocks (12x12, 50lb), on 4x4's on adjustable support brackets.

How do I  laterally brace the structure using this?

Is there a size threshold where I don't need to?

*The bolt just drops a hole in the pier block, there doesn't seem to be any lateral support.*

[image]

Comment: Lateral bracing would negate the adjust-ability of those, would it not?  How big is your shed? These are not really used for things that are above a certain weight, (*i don't know what that weight is*) I do know from experience that if you put to much weight on it you can NOT turn the nut.  Also, 4x4 may not  be  beefy enough for a shed.

Comment: These are typically used in conditions where lateral bracing is provided in some other way, such as a deck attached to a house. The lateral comes from the attachment to the house, not the post supports.

Comment: Perhaps the question should be "Are adjustable brackets the correct support for my shed design?" OR BETTER "What is the best foundation or support for my shed design?" And then include your shed design.

Comment: Where are you located?  If you get any freezing weather, pier blocks are inadvisable and almost certainly against your local building codes.  A shed that may be used for storage might require larger footings than you'd guess, too!  Pier blocks might be used for a small porch or deck, but the basic problem is, topsoil has a low **bearing capacity** and projects are usually easier if you dig deep enough footings to reach better, compacted soil, which may bear 10x as much weight per square foot (so 1/10th as many footings!)

Comment: You're asking an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info) (about a proposed solution rather than your actual problem). I'd back up a few steps and ask about your overall shed floor design. You probably don't need those adjustable gizmos anyway.

Comment: @JeffWheeler, a 12x12 shed may not call for a permit (or code compliance) and really doesn't need frost footings. I've built and owned several in Frost Central. As long as you move some topsoil away you're usually fine.

Comment: He hasn't actually said how big the shed is going to be.  He said 12x12 pier blocks, not 12x12 shed!  That's why I thought it may help to make him aware of some reasons for avoiding a block-on-grade footing.  I have seen plenty of falling down decks & sheds in my area because folks don't know the importance of a good footing.